# Scrapy CSS Selector to select text and blank

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

As I am using scrapy to scrape the site containing the table. I am using the CSS selector for getting the elements for a class attr. Example code is below.

```
<span class="attr">Tamil Nadu - Greenshore Energy</span>
<span class="attr"></span>
<span class="attr">India</span>
```

I an using the selector

```
response.css('.attr::text').extract()
```

To get all the text and blanks in the span. But the above selector is returning only below list. Leaving the empty spans.

> [u'Tamil Nadu - Greenshore Energy', u'India']

So what selector should I use to get all the spans whether it contains the text or not.

Comment: try to get `response.css('.attr::text')` into a var, and then extract manually what you want from that var.

Comment: I am getting this [u'Tamil Nadu - Greenshore Energy', u'India'] even in the variable. What I need it [u'Tamil Nadu - Greenshore Energy', u'', u'India']

Comment: `::text` doesn't give you back empty strings. Try with scrapy xpath. Make sure what returns the methods you use by reading the docs. It will be easier for you to implement things. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> [tag.css('::text').extract_first(default='') for tag in response.css('.attr')]
['Tamil Nadu - Greenshore Energy', '', 'India']
```